# Is there a TMap class in Delphi XE4?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Is there a Java Map like class in Delphi XE4? If it is, some explanation is welcome. I'd like to convert the command prompt params into a map to access them by keys (by expected param names).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [`TDictionary<K,V>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary).